# Do the dots in linked lists represent nodes or pointers from one node to another?

Tags: python, linked-list

I have the following code that reverses a linked list (I know it is correct). I am relatively new to linked list, and I had a few questions about the code itself:

```
 def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
    if head == None:     
        return None
    if head.next == None:     
        return head             

    prev = head
    curr = head
    nex = head.next      

    while nex:                
        curr = nex            
        nex = nex.next        
        curr.next = prev      
        prev = curr
    head.next = None

    return curr
```

I understand the code relating to the two 'if' statements.
Questions:

1. The 'prev' and 'curr' - am I right in saying that those are pointers?
2. In 'nex = head.next'  is 'head.next' referring to the node after head, or the pointer that points from head to the next node?

(Also, what is a 'pointer'- is this what connects one node to another in a linked list?- I understand linked lists, it is just the references in the code I am trying to figure out)

In the while statement:

3. we do 'curr = nex' to move the curr pointer from head to nex (=head.next) - am I reading this correctly?
4. 'nex = nex.next'  what does this do, are we simply assigning nex to nex.next , or are we establishing a connection/address from the node after the head to the node after this node?

The code within the while loop I am struggling to understand, if someone can explain maybe one or two lines that would be really helpful, as I assume most hold the same meaning. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't really have the concept of "pointers" as distinct from "values" the same way that a language like C does.  It might be accurate to say that *every* variable in Python is a "pointer", since variables in Python are always references to objects; reassigning a variable does not change the underlying object (rather, it reassigns it to point at some other object).

> The 'prev' and 'curr' - am I right in saying that those are pointers?

Per the above disclaimer -- yes.

> In 'nex = head.next' is 'head.next' referring to the node after head, or the pointer that points from head to the next node?

Both.  To say that `head.next` "refers to" the node after head is equivalent to saying that it "points to" the next node.  It's the same concept.

> (Also, what is a 'pointer'- is this what connects one node to another in a linked list?- I understand linked lists, it is just the references in the code I am trying to figure out)

A pointer is a thing that "points", which is the same thing as "referring" or "connecting".

> we do 'curr = nex' to move the curr pointer from head to nex (=head.next) - am I reading this correctly?

Yes; when you reassign a variable using the assignment operate (`=`), that variable now points to the thing you just assigned it to.

> 'nex = nex.next' what does this do, are we assigning nex to nex.next , or are we establishing a connection/address from the node after the head to the node after this node?

The variable `nex` is being reassigned to point at whatever `nex.next` points to.  In the context of a linked list, it means you're moving the `nex` pointer one spot forward in the list.

Comment: Hi Samwise, thanks for your comments they are very helpful. One more question please; on the line where we have "curr.next = prev"  ; this curr was assigned previously to nex (curr = nex) and nex was previously assigned to head.next but nex is also later assigned to nex.next ; am I right in assuming that the curr in "curr.next" is referring to curr=nex=head.next?

Comment: Honestly it's a little hard for me to follow what you just asked, but whenever you do an assignment, you're making it so the thing on the left points to whatever object the thing on the right currently points to.  That's all there is to it.  :)  If you find yourself getting confused, add some print statements to the code to help you track what points to what at different times, draw some pictures on paper, etc.